# Using a For-loop to create multiple tables

Tags: r, for-loop, gt

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use for-loops to create multiple tables in one go, all using the same dataset - I'll clarify that in a second. I'm using R Markdown, because I need to compile it in a PDF in the end, if that makes any difference.

So I'm working with one database and trying to separate it into multiple tables (using gt) based on the values of one of the variables. Let's say that my dataset is about towns' annual budgets.

```
data <- data.frame(x=1, y=1:15, z=16:30)
colnames(data) <- c("County", "Town", "Budget")
sample.space <- c(1:5)
number.samples <- 15
data$County <- sample(sample.space, number.samples, replace = TRUE)
sample.space2 <- c(2500:5000)
data$Budget <- sample(sample.space2, number.samples, replace = FALSE)
```

(Please excuse my somewhat clumsy creation, I don't often deal with random numbers these days.)

So what I'd like to do is create separate tables that show the annual budget for all the towns within County X. I've been able to do that just fine by creating new datasets for each county and then making a table from the new dataset. That's fine when you're only looking at 5 counties, but when it's 50, that gets to be a bit cumbersome.

I feel like there should be some way to do this using a for-loop. My gut instinct is to do it like this, but when I compile, nothing prints on the PDF.

```
library(gt)

for (i in 1:5) {
  data[data$County == i, ] %>%
    gt() %>%
    tab_header(
      title = "Annual Budget by County",
    ) 
}
```

If I pick a county and try the same thing without the loop, I have no problem.

```
data[data$County == 1, ] %>%
    gt() %>%
    tab_header(
      title = "Annual Budget for County 1",
    )
```

It's not the end of the world if I can't make it work, but I'm hoping someone more savvy than me can figure it out!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just that in `for` loop the result is not stored based on the OP's code.  We can create a  NULL `list` of `length` 5 and update the `list` with the output based on the sequence looped

```
lst1 <- vector('list', 5)
for (i in 1:5) {
 lst1[[i]] <- data[data$County == i, ] %>%
    gt() %>%
    tab_header(
      title = "Annual Budget by County",
    ) 
}
```

If we want to create multiple objects, it is possible with `assign` but not recommended i.e. it is better to keep it in a `list`

---

Or another option is `split` by 'County' and loop with `lapply` to convert to `gt`

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(data, data$County), function(x) 
              gt(x) %>%
      tab_header(
      title = "Annual Budget by County",
    ) )
```

Comment: Thank you!! This makes a lot of sense.  I was wondering if there was a way to do a split, since I know that's easy enough in SAS, but I'd never tried it in R before. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 6):

*Edit: Since it appears you also want to output each of these in an Rmarkdown document, I've added instructions on how to do that. However, this solution may only work for knitting an html document with the gt package.  Knitting to pdf raises a whole host of other issues outside the scope of this question, but overall you will probably have a better experience using [kables](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html) instead of gt for knitting to pdf.*

Using the `purrr` package from the `tidyverse` for iteration:

```
library(gt)
library(htmltools)
library(tidyverse)

counties <- data$County %>% 
  unique() %>%
  sort()

gt_list <- map(.x = counties,  .f = function(x) {
  data %>%
    filter(County == x) %>%
    gt() %>%
    tab_header(
      title = paste("Annual Budget for County", x),
    ) 
})
```

Then you can wrap your list of gt tables in a tagList from the `htmltools` package to render each of them in your Rmarkdown document:

```
tagList(gt_list)
```

If you absolutely need to knit to pdf, try using kables instead of gt, substituting `map` with `walk` (since you are now only iterating for the side-effect of printing a kable). Also, make sure set the chunk option `results = "asis"`:

````
```{r, results = "asis"}
walk(.x = counties,  .f = function(x) {
  df <- data %>%
    filter(County == x) 
    
  print(knitr::kable(df, caption = paste("Annual Budget for County", x)))
  cat('\n\n\n\n')
})
```
````

And finally, if you simply wanted to just output each gt to its own pdf file (or similar), you could do as follows:

```
walk(.x = counties,  .f = function(x) {
  data %>%
    filter(County == x) %>%
    gt() %>%
    tab_header(
      title = paste("Annual Budget for County", x),
    ) %>%
    gtsave(paste0("County_", x, ".pdf"))
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly with the demo data to compile to a PDF, although once I get back to the more complex tables, we'll see if that still holds. I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem.  I struggled to get the `gt` tables to correctly knit to PDF when specified within a loop (and found others were having the same issues).  I did eventually find a solution though, and since my previous answer was already pretty lengthy, I went ahead and just posted the solution as another answer.  If you run into any issues down the line maybe it'll help.

Comment: Thank you!! I needed to know the pdf version. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I was able to find two extremely helpful links that solved my Knit to PDF issues with gt tables created within a loop. YMMV:

1. Use [as_latex()](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/as_latex.html)
2. [Modify](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-output-a-gt-table-object-into-a-rmarkdown-document-pdf/23146/4) your Rmarkdown yaml

So, your entire Rmarkdown file might look something like this:

````
---
title: "gt package pdf output"
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption} # Insert the package used by gt
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

data <- data.frame(x=1, y=1:15, z=16:30)
colnames(data) <- c("County", "Town", "Budget")
sample.space <- c(1:5)
number.samples <- 15
data$County <- sample(sample.space, number.samples, replace = TRUE)
sample.space2 <- c(2500:5000)
data$Budget <- sample(sample.space2, number.samples, replace = FALSE)

counties <- data$County %>% 
  unique() %>%
  sort()

```

```{r, results="asis"}

walk(.x = counties,  .f = function(x) {
  data %>%
    filter(County == x) %>%
    gt() %>%
    tab_header(
      title = paste("Annual Budget for County", x),
    ) %>%
    as_latex() %>% 
    as.character() %>%
    cat()
})

```
````